# Ubuntu detects different keyboard on laptop

Tags: windows

I'm using WMware player on my windows 7 laptop. Whenever I press the keys j,k,l,u,i,p, i get 1,2,3,4,5,6 respectively. I see these numbers on my laptop too but I want regular leters. thanks!

Comment: Is your NumLock on? Or some similar switch on your Laptop?

Comment: No, I turned off my number lock. I still get wrong letter when I Type

Answer (score 0):

You have number lock turned on. Turn Number Lock off.

Comment: I turned off number lock, still same issue